# How to reorder/reverse the rows of a contingency table generated by [expss]?

Tags: r, expss

I use expss to generate a contingency table.

```
rawdata %>% 
  tab_cells(A1) %>% 
  tab_cols(total(), R4) %>% 
  tab_stat_cpct() %>% 
  tab_pivot() %>% 
  if_na(0)
```

A1's values and labels are:

```
1 Dislike very much
2 Dislike
3 Neither
4 Like
5 Like very much
```

R4 is for gender.

Therefore, in the output the row order is from "Dislike very much" to "Like very much" (with value 1 to 5).

|  |  | #Total | Male | Female |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product liking | Dislike very much | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
|  | Dislike | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.0 |
|  | Neither | 4.4 | 5.4 | 3.5 |
|  | Like | 53.1 | 51.4 | 54.6 |
|  | Like very much | 42.4 | 43.0 | 41.9 |
|  | #Total cases | 892.0 | 407.0 | 485.0 |

However, I hope it could be shown form "Like very much" to "Dislike very much" (with value 5 to 1), like:

|  |  | #Total | Male | Female |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product liking | Like very much | 42.4 | 43.0 | 41.9 |
|  | Like | 53.1 | 51.4 | 54.6 |
|  | Neither | 4.4 | 5.4 | 3.5 |
|  | Dislike | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.0 |
|  | Dislike very much | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
|  | #Total cases | 892.0 | 407.0 | 485.0 |

In the spss, there is a button to decide the ascending or descending order, but I did not find any in the expss.

I have tried the "tab_sort_desc()" but it seems to order the rows based on the specific columns' value rather than value of row label. I tried others but still failed.

Hope anyone could help me out with this question, thank you!

Comment: I'm not using `expss`, but can you convert the values into factors and control the levels? For instance `sort(factor(c("A","C","B","C")))` will wort as `A,B,C,C` (alpha by default), but `sort(factor(c("A","C","B","C"), levels=c("C","A","B")))` (explicit list of unique levels within the factor, and in the order you want) will sort them as `C,C,A,B`. From there, you can order your frame-like object via normal R sorting methods.

Comment: @r2evans thank you! I tried to convert a variable to the factor, and it works! Unfortunately, I have **many variables with different value names**. It will be a bit inconvenient if I need to convert them one by one. Any solutions for this issues? THANK YOU!

Comment: `fct_rev`, from the `forcats` package, reverses the order of a factor's levels. Maybe this can help you in getting a more general solution

Comment: You should be able to reverse the factor levels on-the-fly by replacing `tab_cells(A1) %>%` with `tab_cells(forcats::fct_rev(A1)) %>%`.  The`forcats` package needs to be installed.

Comment: Valerie, I'm glad you made some progress. I think we can give you working code, but it's be far easier and more accurate of you could give us a sample of your data. Please [edit] your question and paste the output from `dput(head(raw data,20))` (or some size that gives is enough variability to get they point).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, the simplest way is to recode your variables in an opposite direction:

```
rawdata %>%
    let(
        # labels also recoded automatically
        # in this example we recode range of variables
        (A1 %to% A10) := rec(A1 %to% A10, from_to(1:0, 0:1), TRUE ~ copy)    
    ) %>% 
    tab_cells(A1) %>% 
    tab_cols(total(), R4) %>% 
    tab_stat_cpct() %>% 
    tab_pivot() %>% 
    if_na(0)
```

Comment: Hi Gregory, really appreciate your answer. These codes keep the labels and show correct results. It works!